# Parse CloudCode Init Method

Tags: parse-platform

Is there a method that gets called the first time a version of cloud code is run?  I need a place to setup my role hierarchy and crate a master admin user, things like that.  I just want to run that code once when a new version of my cloud code deployment is run for the first time.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think anything like that exists, but you shouldn't need it anyways. Shouldn't role hierarchies and master users be independent from cloud code releases?

Comment: Yeah. But when I tried creating the role hierarchies in the web interface I can't seem to add the parent role.  I'm not sure how to add a pointer to a row in the web interface.  So I wanted to have a method in cloud code to set all that up.  But I don't want to have it running queries to the check the roles all the time.  Is there a configuration key value store in parse that I can use to flag setup?